# Customized UIPickerView and components

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, multi-select

How can I create a multi select picker? I've a list of items and I want them to show in a picker with the option to multi select them, with checkmarks.

I've seen this while using an app, can somebody explain how this can be achieved?

I somehow solved the it partially, but can't figure out how to put checkmarks on the left, this is what I did

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
  UILabel *label = (UILabel*) view;
if (label == nil)
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}

[label setText:@"Whatever"];    
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
CGSize rowSize = [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component];
CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, rowSize.width, rowSize.height);
[label setFrame:labelRect];

return label;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement UIPickerViewDelegate methods, in your case i believe  `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` is the one you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you point me to a sample code or anything that I can look into. Being a newbie, it's hard for me to understand exactly how you mean. Please help.

Comment: I somehow solved it partially, but can't figure out how to put checkmarks on the left. I've updated my post, please have a look at the code and help me.